# How to use web3 in React?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, truffle, web3-react

In order to use web3 in react, I imported web3 like this,

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

However, I got this error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'web3' in '/Users/___/Desktop/MyApps/eth_todo_react/frontend/src'
```

I used to use web3, but the error come up from yesterday.

Could you give me any advise, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it is added to your package.json and try an `npm install` or even delete node_modules and `npm install`.